# float object not subscriptable (python)

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, jupyter, jupyter-lab

So I am creating 10 dictionaries from a data-frame.

I have already done 3 for each row, but I have decided to do one for every column in my data-frame. When I add the 7 additional dictionaries, I get a float object not subscriptable error. What's confusing is, I had already added the additional 7 dictionary entries for a few other rows. Even more confusing, the error is on a line where the dictionary entries had already been successfully assigned and not for the entries I'm adding to one of the 7 additional dictionaries. Here's my code, please help if you can.

```
pace[b[1]] = bList[1]
offEff[b[1]] = bList[9]
defEff[b[1]] = bList[10]
ast[b[1]] = bList[2]
to[b[1]] = bList[3]
orr[b[1]] = bList[4]
drr[b[1]] = bList[5]
rebr[b[1]] = bList[6]
effFG[b[1]] = bList[7]
tsPer[b[1]] = bList[8]
```

I'm using JupyterLab, if that helps.

Comment: From your rambling description I can't tell which expression is producing the error.  The error says that in one of those `foo[...]` expressions, `foo` is actually a number, not a dictionary or list.  We can't guess which.  You need to check the type of the variables in the problem line.  Once you've determined which variable is the problem, you can move to figuring out why it's a number rather than an indexable object.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the `bList` is a list object.According to your description,the `bList` may be a float in your code:

```
>>> a=1.0
>>> a[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```